# How can you tell programmatically if a Word Macro is signed from VB.Net/C#

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, ms-word

I have an VB.Net/C# application that programmatically:

1. Creates an RTF document
2. Open it up in Microsoft Word
3. Runs a Word macro that exists in the Word Template using code like this:

Code:

```
Protected mobjWordApp As Word.Application = Nothing
'
' lots more code snipped for clarity
'
With mobjWordApp.Dialogs.Item(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogToolsMacro)
    .Name = MacroName
    .Run = True
    .Execute()
End With
```

This has worked happily for years.

I now have a new requirement; My application is required to only run SIGNED Word Macros.

This is easy enough to do in the Word user interface, as follows:

```
File > Options > Trust center > Macro Settings
Select "Disable all macros except digitally signed macros"
```

[image: Trust Center]

Once this is set, if the person running Word displays the Macros dialog, any unsigned (or signed but untrusted) macros are not listed. This is all as I would expect.

However, my VB.Net code, which is opening the Word Application can bypass this. When I run this code it will run a unsigned macro:

```
With mobjWordApp.Dialogs.Item(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogToolsMacro)
    .Name = MacroName
    .Run = True
    .Execute()
End With
```

What I need to know is:

Is there a way for my code to identify if a Macro is signed (and trusted) before I run it?

Comment: What version of word doc ? doc or docx ?

Comment: G'day Micah, we're running Word 2007 (32-bit) with .dotm and .doc files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim ap As New Application()
Dim doc As Document = ap.Documents.Open("C:\Doc1.rtf", [ReadOnly] := False, Visible :=        False)
doc.Activate()
'returns a boolean on if the VBA is signed 
doc.VBASigned
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.vbasigned%28v=office.11%29.aspx)